# populate Excel Formulas in the an entire column after changing some of the formula values

Tags: excel-formula

I have two  excel sheets. The one that contains the data "gdsc_en_input_w2" and the other one will contain a selective number of cells from "gdsc_en_input_w2".

I am using the current formula:

=INDEX(gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$YE$13848,MATCH("AKT2",gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$A$13848,0),MATCH(**$A$3**,gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$YE$1,0))

I want to fill an entire column in the second sheet by referencing columns in the "gdsc_en_input_w2" sheet  but based on the values stored in the column $A$1:$A$13848. As you can see the second match() matches only $A$3 ...is there a way to fill the required column with the formula with incremental column reference in the second match() function in the formula above. in other words I want to fill in the second cell of the target column the following formula :

=INDEX(gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$YE$13848,MATCH("AKT2",gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$A$13848,0),MATCH(**$A$4**,gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$YE$1,0))

note that the match now has $A$4 instead of $A$3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I am understanding what you are wanting, this formula is going to be in one column where each subsequent row will have a higher number (3,4,5,...) If that is the case, unlock your formula to read:

=INDEX(gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$YE$13848,MATCH("AKT2",gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$A$13848,0),MATCH($A3,gdsc_en_input_w2!$A$1:$YE$1,0))  (I removed the $ in-front of the 3)

Paste that into the whatever your starting cell is, then auto-fill

Comment: it worked on my office excel but on my mac it is complaint about the sheet reference. there could be a syntax problem which I am trying to find right now.

Comment: I tried that ...in 2010  the sheet name has the file extension which I did not have . when I added it worked. I tried to change "AKT2" to be the row ID "I2" so that I can copy it across the row but it did not work is there a specia rule?